# Pass a List of integers to a C# controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, controller, http-post

I am trying to pass in a list of integers to a C# controller action. I have the following code:

```
    HttpRequestMessage request;
    String myUrl = 'http://path/to/getData';
    List<int> data = new List<int>() { 4, 6, 1 };

    request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.post, myUrl);
    request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented));

    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
    String responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var data = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseString);
```

The controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("getData")]
    public Response getData(List<int> myInts) {

        // ...

    }
```

However the resulting `responseString` is:

```
 {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'List`1' from content with media type 'text/plain'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Comment: If one of the answers has helped you, please upvote and mark it as the answer.  If your question is still unanswered, please let us know.  If you found a different answer to your question, please post it as an answer.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816493/pass-listint-from-actionlink-to-controller-method) - you are not sending a `List<int>`, you are sending a serialized list of integers (in this case, a JSON serialized string).  So you need to accept a string and deserialize at the other end, as well as handling any non-integer values that might be encountered.  Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("getData")]
public Response getData(string myInts) {

    var myIntsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(myInts);
    // Don't forget error handling!

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

The other alternative is to add multiple query parameters like so:

`http://path/to/getData?myInts=4&myInts=6&myInts=1`

<s>This should work with the code that you have already.</s> ASP.NET can interpret multiple query parameters as a `List<T>`).

Sorry, you may need to add the `[FromUri]` attribute for the solution:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("getData")]
public Response getData([FromUri]List<int> myInts) {

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you utilize [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) package in client application

Action method

```
// POST api/values
        public void Post(List<int> value)
        {
        }
```

client application

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:24932/api/values",
                    new List<int>() {123, 123, 123}).Result;

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```